gitlab project token - who was the creator
Is there an easy way to find out who created an access token for a project on gitlab?
In the project on gitlab I navigate to Settings -> Access Tokens
I see there is a token created with a not very descriptive name. The token has to be deployed to the machines and the Last Used counter says never. So only the half work was done. I want to avoid that two people work on the same issue so it would be helpful to talk to the initial creator for further steps.
